# How to implement Passwordless authentication with custom code and lifetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, password-less

I'm trying to have passwordless authentication with with custom lifetime and 6 digit code.
So far I implemented it with `DataProtectorTokenProvider`. lifetime has been changed correctly and also I can create 6 digit code but `VerifyUserTokenAsync` returns `false`.

Here is my code :

```
    public static class CustomIdentityBuilderExtensions
    {            
        public static IdentityBuilder AddPasswordlessLoginTokenProvider(this IdentityBuilder builder)
        {
            var userType = builder.UserType;
            var provider = typeof(PasswordlessLoginTokenProvider<>).MakeGenericType(userType);
            return builder.AddTokenProvider("PasswordlessLoginProvider", provider);
        }
    }
    public class PasswordlessLoginTokenProviderOptions : DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions
    {
        public PasswordlessLoginTokenProviderOptions()
        {
            // update the defaults
            Name = "PasswordlessLoginTokenProvider";
            TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        }
    }
        public override async Task<string> GenerateAsync(string purpose, UserManager<TUser> manager, TUser user)
        {
            // This will generate 6 digit code but in validation it doesn't work
            Random generator = new();
            string token = generator.Next(0, 1000000).ToString("D6");
            return Task.FromResult(token);
        }

        public override Task<bool> CanGenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(UserManager<TUser> manager, TUser user)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(false);
        }
    }
```

I generate the token with `GenerateUserTokenAsync` :

```
string confirmationToken = await _userManager.GenerateUserTokenAsync(user, "PasswordlessLoginProvider", "passwordless-auth");
```

And here `VerifyUserTokenAsync` returns `false`:

```
 bool isValid = await _userManager.VerifyUserTokenAsync(user, "PasswordlessLoginProvider", "passwordless-auth", token);
```

**Note:** I also tried `TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider` but it doesn't support changing codes lifetime.

**Update:**

This is how `DataProtectorTokenProvider` generates the code.[github repo](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Core/src/DataProtectorTokenProvider.cs):

```
 public virtual async Task<string> GenerateAsync(string purpose, UserManager<TUser> manager, TUser user)
        {
            if (user == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
            }
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            var userId = await manager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
            using (var writer = ms.CreateWriter())
            {
                writer.Write(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow);
                writer.Write(userId);
                writer.Write(purpose ?? "");
                string? stamp = null;
                if (manager.SupportsUserSecurityStamp)
                {
                    stamp = await manager.GetSecurityStampAsync(user);
                }
                writer.Write(stamp ?? "");
            }
            var protectedBytes = Protector.Protect(ms.ToArray());
            return Convert.ToBase64String(protectedBytes);
        }
```

Comment: if you are overriding/customizing `GenerateAsync` then you would have also override `ValidateAsync` to provide validation logic.

Comment: @CodingMytra thank you, but how can I implement that?

Comment: first thing you have to store the token or if it is already stored then you have to read it and compare against what your are getting in VerifyUserTokenAsync method. but why do you need custom 6 digit code you can use default one it will make thing easy

Comment: @Kaveh A very naive implementation would be to store the token somewhere and whenever the identity comes back, check if the token is the one you've saved

Comment: @CodingMytra the default code is a very long string but I just want a number to send back to user

Comment: there is also a validation logic in the same file [github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Core/src/DataProtectorTokenProvider.cs), since you have written your own token  generation code, you need to write validation logic also.